# Set value of a int from an NSarray

Tags: objective-c

how can I set an int to a value from array ?
I try like that:

```
    int counter;
    counter = signArr[4];
```

doesn't work, I get an err " incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id' "

thank for help :)

Comment: What is the object in the array? What methods does it offer?

Comment: the object "singarr[4]" is hold an number that comes from my db. that mean that singarr[4] = 6 or other number

Comment: Arrays can't contain primitives like an int. If your array contains numbers, they're probably NSNumber objects, so you have to use intValue to convert it.

Comment: `NSArray` can only contain objects, an integer is not an object. In order to contain an integer it must first be converted to an `NSNumber`. This can be either with a method call of a literal such as `@2`. When obtaining this from the array an `NSInteger` would be obtained and that would have to be converted back to an integer with a nut hod such as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment we can guess that the number is boxed in an `NSNumber` instance. We can test with a log statement (or in the debugger):

```
NSLog(@"The class is %@", NSStringFromClass[signArr[4] class]));
```

and then, if it is an `NSNumber` instance, looking at the methods on offer we can see [`integerValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/integerValue) which will provide what you're looking for.

The error you saw

> incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id'

tells you that you want an `int` but that you have an `id`. You should know that `id` is the generic pointer type used in ObjC (if you don't you need to go and read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW18) some more) and thus you need to find a way to convert from the object pointer to the primitive int. The first step is finding out what the object class type is and then checking the docs to see what it offers you to help achieve your goal.